# typeerror:indices must be an integer not str how can i resolve

Tags: python, python-2.7

while I am writing my code

```
for i in str_list:
    bin_list.append(codes[i]);
    bin=bin+codes[i];
```

it says indices must be an integer not str. I want to do it for all characters in `str_list`.

Comment: And what is `codes` here? What is the desired output? Do you have sample input, what is *in* `str_list`?

Comment: Pro tip: Python code does not need `;` semicolons. You can remove those without consequence.

Comment: str_list contains sequence of characters

Answer (score 2):

For loops in python gives you values, and not indicies, if you want indices, do this:

```
for i, var in enumerate(str_list): ...
```

A demo:

```
>>> h = "hello world"
>>> for i in h: print i
h
e
l
l
o

w
o
r
l
d
```

However, using `enumerate`:

```
>>> for i, var in enumerate(h): print i
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

You get the indexes. Please note, that `enumerate` gives you a `tuple`. What I mean by this is:

```
>>> for var in enumerate(h): print var
(0, 'h')
(1, 'e')
(2, 'l')
(3, 'l')
(4, 'o')
(5, ' ')
(6, 'w')
(7, 'o')
(8, 'r')
(9, 'l')
(10, 'd')
```

So, when we say for `i, var in ...`, we split the tuple into two. The first value, the index goes to `i`, and the second value, `var` goes to the actual value.

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in str_list:
```

will not give indices to the characters in the string but the actual characters themselves, as string. What you need is this

```
for i in xrange(len(str_list)):
```

Now, `i` will be giving you the indices. Read about [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)

**Edit** Sometimes, you might want the index as well as the actual character corresponding to that index. Instead of doing

```
for i in xrange(len(str_list)):
    str_list[i]
```

you can use [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for index, char in enumerate(str_list):
```

Comment: Generally, you would want to use `enumerate()` to generate indices; but it is far from clear what the OP wants here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh, I didnt know that `enumerate` is a generator. I ll add that also in the answer.

Comment: @thefourtheye already added enumerate, heheheheh

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Oops. Sorry, I just saw that.

Comment: @thefourtheye I know what you mean man, answering questions is a race these days.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac You got me bro ;) But we both are learning a lot daily :)